# <h:selectOneMenu>'s value not submitted correctly

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, selectonemenu

In my application, I have the following piece of code:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="initPanel" columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="type" value="*Type: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu label="type" id="type" value="#{createNews.type}"
                         required="true" requiredMessage="Type is required.">
            <f:ajax render="typePanel" />
            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Choose one..." />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Article" itemLabel="Article" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Video"   itemLabel="Video" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p:message for="type" />

        <h:outputLabel for="title" value="*Title: " />
        <p:inputText label="title" id="title" 
                     value="#{createNews.news.title}" 
                     required="true" requiredMessage="Title is required." />
        <p:message for="title" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGroup id="typePanel">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{createNews.type == 'Article'}" columns="1">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="content" value="*Content: " />
                <p:message id="contentMsg" for="content" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:editor id="content" value="#{createNews.news.content}" width="580" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{createNews.type == 'Video'}" columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="embedCode" value="*Embed code: " />
            <p:inputText label="embedCode" id="embedCode" 
                         value="#{createNews.news.embedCode}" />
            <p:message for="embedCode" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:commandButton value="Confirm" update="initPanel typePanel" actionListener="#{createNews.createNews}" />

</h:form>
```

And this is the managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "createNews")
@RequestScoped
public class CreateNews {
    private Integer type;
    private News    news;

    public void createNews() {...}

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I choose `Article` or `Video`, the corresponding portion is rendered correctly in `typePanel`. In the below example, I chose `Video` and the `Embed code` portion was rendered.

[image: The Embed code portion is rendered correctly.]

However, when I click `Confirm`, the portion rendered earlier suddenly disappear.

[image: The Embed code portion disappeared!]

Somehow, the `type` property of my managed bean did not receive the value of the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you show us the code of createNews() ?

Comment: @MurifoX is it related to the problem? I don't think this method would be called since several properties such as `Title` are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the following 2 facts:

- A request scoped bean is created on every request (including ajax requests).
- Model values are not updated in case of a general validation failure.

When you change the dropdown, you're creating one request scoped bean wherein the right property for the `rendered` attribute is been set. But the request scoped bean is of course garbaged by end of request. When you submit the confirm button, a brand new request scoped bean is created with all properties set to default which are not updated due to a general validation failure, that's why the `rendered` attribute evaluates back to `false`.

Placing the bean in the JSF view scope or CDI conversation scope should solve it.

An alternative is to bind the dropdown to an [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) in the current view scope and evaluate the selected value by its [`UIInput#getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html#getValue%28%29) instead.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu ... binding="#{type}">
...
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{type.value == 'Article'}">
...
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{type.value == 'Embed'}">
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! I have 2 small questions. Are there any other ways beside using `@ViewScoped` or `@ConversationScope`? If 1000 or more users are creating posts, will it cost a lot of resources if I use `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: I recently updated the answer. Performance impact is negligible as the view is already stored in session anyway. You're basically just binding the bean to the view.

Comment: I was actually using `binding` earlier but I had no idea why it worked. I do now :P. Thanks again!